# Querying associated models using MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express

I’m trying to setup an model association using [MEAN](http://mean.io/) where an Epic has many Tasks.  I’m creating the Epic first then associating it when creating a task. The task data model looks like this with the Epic associated:

```
task:
   { name: 'my first task',
     epic:
      { name: 'My fist epic',
        _id: 52f511c605456ba4c936180d,
        __v: 0},
     _id: 52f511d605456ba4c936180e,
     __v: 0 } }
```

In my public Epics controller I’m trying to query for all the tasks with the current Epic’s ID but I’m I’m not having much luck. The query below returns ALL tasks instead of the tasks associated with my Epic.

```
Tasks.query({“epic._id": $routeParams.epicId}, function(tasks) {
    $scope.tasks = tasks;
});
```

Is there a better way to do association and retrieval using MEAN? I’m a bit of a noob.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I've playing around with the idea of updating the epic when a new task is created. In app/controllers/tasks.js I have this code that doesn't work.

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var task = new Task(req.body)
  Epic.find(req.body.epic.id, function (err, epic) {
    if (err) return next(err)
    epic.tasks.push(task.id);
    epic.save();
  })
  task.save()
  res.jsonp(task)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you also using mongoose? I would use the "ref" and "populate".
First you have a TaskSchema.

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({  ...  });
mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

add the model etc, then you you reference it in your other schema. I'll add an example of 1 or multiple task(s).

```
var Schema = new Schema({
   task: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Task'
   },
   tasks: [
     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Task'}
   ]
});
```

and then to call it with populate.

```
this.findOne({
    _id: id
}).populate('tasks').exec(cb);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Dylan. I AM using mongoose. Based on my project, the other schema would be the parent schema for an Epic, right? If I followed your suggestion how would I update the epic model when I create a new task? In your suggestion you list the "populate" method which I'm assuming is useful for rendering after the tasks has already been associated with the epic. I was thinking maybe I should try finding and updating the parent epic from the create method in my server side controller for tasks. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need help debugging xhr. Let's trace the steps:

- Is your request making it to the server?
- Is it arriving at the correct express route?
- Is your server-side code performing the correct find operation against Mongo?
- Is Mongo returning the right results?
- Are you writing the results from Mongo into the response correctly?
- Are you able to see the response on the client by inspecting the network traffic using your browser's dev tools?
- Are you handling the promise success correctly?

You'll need to post more info and code to know where the problem lies.